# Max- Min Normalization range related confusion

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, scaling

I am using UCI Machine Learning banking dataset for data preprocessing.[URL](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing) I use Max- Min Normalization method to normalize the data.

[image]

As per my knowledge This method rescales the range of the data to [0,1].

The original data looks like

[image]

After applying data normalization

```
df.duration = df.duration.apply(lambda v:((v df.duration.min())/df.duration.max()-df.duration.min()))
```

Now the data looks like

[image]

After normalizing duration column all data became negative. But as per Max-Min normalization data should be in between (0,1). Therefore, which normalization gives better performance here?

I am getting confused because I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePHZlT1XjrA&list=LL&index=2&t=580s) to gain knowledge. As per the video duration column in between 0,1. However, when I ran the same code in my machine I got something different.

Comment: As per formula, MinMax scaling would require the Min value to be subtracted from the elements, but you're subtracting the Mean value. That might be the reason why you're getting the negative values.

Comment: I edit my code and output. The output is the same as previous. I got (-) values.

Comment: Just to make sure, is that the exact code you run? It's missing a minus between v and df.duration.min() and df.duration.max() - df.duration.min() are not grouped together inside parentheses, which means you subrtact Min value from v, divide it by max, and the subtract Min value from the result. This will also result in negative values.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Basically the problem is relate to bracket. It works well when I group df.duration.max() - df.duration.min().

Comment: I'm not really sure whether you want to close the question or for me to type out an answer for you to accept so the question is closed, as I feel the problem stemming from, essentially, a typo (that being the reason why I clarified things in comments instead of posting an answer)?

Comment: I admit that there is a typo in my question. However, as I got lots of downvotes I lost my access to type a really important question in stack overflow. I believed this community is a blessing for struggling coders. However, now I feel that people are much willing to downvote all the time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the line `diff = df['balance'].max() - df['duration'].min()` for `diff = df['balance'].max() - df['balane'].min()`. You are computing `diff` from different variables.

Also review the implementation. According to [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) the correct implementation is:

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

Putting all together:

```
# Compute min and max just once

MIN = df['duration'].min()
MAX = df['duration'].max()

# Max Min Scaler function

def MinMaxScaler(X):
    return (X - MIN) / (MAX - MIN)

# Scale the duration variable

df['duration'] = df['duration'].apply(MinMaxScaler)
```

Comment: Can you please change the formula as per 'duration' column?